# How to modify data in within an array from a template without without affecting the original data in angular

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, data-binding

i wants to modify and object within an array without altering the original array as
in the original array looks like:

```
books:Book[] = [{author:"John Doe",title:"Javascript"},{author:"John Doe",title:"Javascript"}]
selectedBook:Book = Books[1];
```

within HTML template, i have:

```
<input [(ngModel)]=selectedBook.name/>
<table>
   <tr *ngFor = "let book of books">
       <td>{{book.name}}</td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

now whenever the value of the input changes it's reflects on both the 'selectedBook' and the object within the array thus, changes the table value as well event though the input value is binds to copied object which is 'selectedBook', so how do i modify the object at position 1 in the array without modifying the original object in the array

Comment: I think that you need two copies of the array, do you have a problem with that?

Answer (score 0):

You can use **Object.assign()** to clone an object.By using it changes made to the cloned object will not get reflected to the original object in the books array

```
books:Book[] = [{author:"John Doe",title:"Javascript"},{author:"John Doe",title:"Javascript"}]
selectedBook:Book = Object.assign({},Books[1]);
```

For more info about Object.assign() read the link below

https://googlechrome.github.io/samples/object-assign-es6/

Comment: still given same result. no changes